Write a proper nested query Rails
This is the domain model of my app:

Here is the repository: https://github.com/AJuliette/paris-fresh
For some data viz I wanted to get some data, I didn't succeed using Active Records and I used maps but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do it in Active Records (or even SQL)
1)
<% FreshPlace.all.group_by(&:place_type).map do |place_type, fresh_places| %>
    <%= pie_chart fresh_places.map { |fresh_place| fresh_place.neighborhood_number }.tally, donut: true %>
<% end %>

For the pie chart I needed data like this:
{75020=>1, 75012=>1, 75018=>1, 75014=>1, 75019=>1, 75010=>1, 75013=>1}
=> {fresh_place.neighborhood_number: count of fresh_places in this neighborhood} for each fresh_place
Here is the query/mapping if you want to reproduce it in rails c:
FreshPlace.all.group_by(&:place_type).map { |place_type, fresh_places| fresh_places.map { |fresh_place| fresh_place.neighborhood_number }.tally}




<% Neighborhood.all.map do |neighborhood| %>
     <%= pie_chart neighborhood.fresh_places.group(:place_type).count.map{ |place_type, number| [place_type, number]}.to_h %>
<% end %>

For the pie chart I need data like this: {"misting_device"=>1, "district_town_hall"=>1, "place_of_worship"=>4, "permanent_shade_structure"=>2, "museum"=>6}
=> fresh_place.place_type: number of fresh places of the same place type for each neighborhood
Here is the query/mapping if you want to reproduce it in rails c:
Neighborhood.all.map { |neighborhood| neighborhood.fresh_places.group(:place_type).count.map{ |place_type, number| [place_type, number]}.to_h}


Neighborhood.group(:number)
            .left_joins(:fresh_places)
            .sum(FreshPlace.arel_table[:id].count)

Make sure you add a unique index to neighborhoods.number to avoid duplicates although what you're using actully looks like the postal code.
In general avoid using the enumerable methods such as map, group_by and tally on ActiveRecord models. You're pulling everything out of the database which will ruin the performance of your app or even crash it if you exhaust the available memory.
Databases are really good at counting things so use it.
You should also avoid denormalizing the other tables by storing both the neighborhood id and number. Either use the natural key (number) for the relation or the surrogate key (id) and get the number by joining the neighborhood. There should be one source of truth.
